# Disable / Remove link to Product Items in Cart

Tags: magento2, cart, link

By default, when you go to the Cart, You see all the products you purchased on the left hand column and also all the products are linked to their individual product page.

I'd like to remove that link as some of the products in our store are not supposed to link out to their individual product pages. Been trying to locate that in my theme and store, but on luck. Any idea what file I can locate it to disable the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove product link form product name on cart page, you need to copy:

> Magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

You can find `product-item-name` which has product URL, you can remove/edit from here.

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</strong>
```

**Update I**

If you also want to remove link from minicart, You need to copy:

> Magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

You can remove link form below code:

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! What about the mini-cart? Where would I locate that code?

Comment: welcome@AdamBell, Please see my updates in answer.

Comment: That’s what I thought it was. Since the a href was using a data-bind, I changed it to a span, removed the reference to href: product_url and resaved it and uploaded it from my child theme. Problem is I’m not seeing the change on the site even after flushing Magento cache.

Comment: @AdamBell, you also need to remove `pub/static/frontend` folder to see changes.

Comment: Tried that. Cleared Static Cache in Terminal as well. No luck. Never took the file change, so it's still showing the original a instead of the new span.

Comment: if you are on production mode, you need to deploy content as well.

Comment: @AdamBell, Can you please magento version?

Comment: v2.2.25.. It's a staging site.

Comment: We already ran static-content:deploy last night in Terminal.No luck.

Comment: Doing it via the XML seems a cleaner method - see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270822/disable-remove-link-to-product-items-in-cart